# How huge amount of data is inputted in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am new to big data and hadoop. I would like to know are name node, data node, secondary name node, job tracker, task tracker different systems ?  If i want to process 1000 PB data, How data is divided and who is doing that task and where should i input 1000 PB data.

Comment: please share with what you have tried so far until now.

Comment: I have just the theoretical knowledge from websites. No practical knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `namenode, dataNode, secondaryNameNode, jobTracker, taskTracker` are all different `virtual machines` (`JVM`s you can call them). You can start them all in one physical machine (`pseudo/local mode`) or you can start them on different physical machines (`distributed mode`). These are all in Hadoop1.

`Hadoop2` has introduced containers with `YARN` in which `jobTracker` and `taskTracer` are removed with more efficient `resourceManager`, `applicationManager`, `nodeManager` etc. You can find more info [hadoop-yarn-site](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)

Data are stored in `HDFS` (`Hadoop Distributed File System`) and are stored in `blocks`, default to `64MB`. When data is loaded to `hdfs`, `hadoop` distributes the data equally in the cluster with the defined block size. When a job is run code is distributed to the nodes in cluster so that each processing occurs where the data is residing except in `shuffle` and `sorting` cases.

I hope you must have general idea of how `hadoop` and `hdfs` works. Followings are some links for you to start with 
[Map Reduce programming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)
[cluster setup](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html)
[hadoop commands](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_command_reference.htm)

Comment: Ok. I like to know the working of hadoop and hdfs If i have to process huge amount of data. How should i input it

Comment: I guess you must have gone through all of the links I have shared. You can try [simple word count](https://dzone.com/articles/word-count-hello-word-program-in-mapreduce) in wihich its explained how you can access hdfs and use hadoop and how hadoop works.